Rotating a 3×3×3 matrix
I am trying to create a Rubik simulation. I represented my cube as 3d array of cubies and I want to rotate the faces of the cube. How can I update the state of the cube after the rotation animation finish ? Is there some other way to model cube making the state update of the cube much easier ? Here is my cube representation :

and these are my cubie and rubik cube classes:


class Cubie {
  constructor(x, y, z, len) {
    this.len = len;
    this.vertices = this.getVertices(x, y, z);
    this.faces = this.getFaces(vertices);
  }

  getVertices(x, y, z) {
    const A = new Vertex(x, y, z);
    const B = new Vertex(x + this.len, y, z);
    const C = new Vertex(x + this.len, y, z + this.len);
    const D = new Vertex(x, y, z + this.len);
    const E = new Vertex(x, y + this.len, z);
    const F = new Vertex(x + this.len, y + this.len, z);
    const G = new Vertex(x + this.len, y + this.len, z + this.len);
    const H = new Vertex(x, y + this.len, z + this.len);
    return [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H];
  }
  getFaces(vertices) {
    const [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H] = vertices;
    const backFace = [A, E, F, B];
    const leftFace = [B, F, G, C];
    const frontFace = [C, G, H, D];
    const rightFace = [D, H, E, A];
    const downFace = [D, A, E, C];
    const upFace = [E, H, G, F];
    return [backFace, leftFace, frontFace, rightFace, downFace, upFace];
  }

  drawFace(face) {
    const [vertex0, vertex1, vertex2, vertex3] = face;
    const triangle1 = new Triangle(vertex0, vertex1, vertex2);
    const triangle2 = new Triangle(vertex2, vertex3, vertex0);
    // TO-DO: draw trinangle1 and triangle2
    
  }
}


class RubikCube {
  constructor(x, y, z, len, dim) {
    this.dim = dim;
    this.len = len;
    this.cubies = this.getCubies(x, y, z);
  }

  getCubies(x, y, z) {
    let cubies = [];
    const cubieLen = this.len / 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dim; i++) {
      let layer = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.dim; j++) {
        let row = [];
        for (let k = 0; k < this.dim; k++) {
          const u = cubieLen * (i - 3 / 2) - x;
          const v = cubieLen * (j - 3 / 2) - y;
          const w = cubieLen * (k - 3 / 2) - z;
          row.push(new Cubie(u, v, w, cubieLen));
        }
        layer.push(row);
      }
      cubies.push(layer);
    }
    return cubies;
  }
}




Your question does not mention anything about what programming language or software tool you are using for this. Please add the relevant tag to the question, and provide your attempt as a [mre]. Explain precisely where you are stuck.

I didn' t implement the logic yet. I wanna an idea how to achieve rotation in the logic level before going any further. So if my cube modeling is complicated i can modify it in this early stage

I only spotted this question now. If you are still interested in an answer, let me know, and I'll work on posting an answer.
